# How does climate change affect air density?

Tags: density, climate-science

At first I thought... if the overall temperature of a planet goes up, then the gaseous atmosphere will be hotter, so it will have lower density than it used to. So overall density should go down.

Then I started looking at the equations, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_of_air, and I got a bit lost.

For example, if humidity is important to calculate density, what happens if the wind patterns shift, for example if the Trade Winds move North? Can global humidity level all go up? What do the models predict?

Comment: Hi Don and welcome to the Physics SE. I don't think this is a question about physics and I suspect you'd get better answers on the [Earth Science Stack Exchange](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/).